# Can I use throw without any message?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Here is my code:

```
try {

    if ( condition 1 ) {
        throw;
    } else {
        // do something
    }

    // some code here

    if ( condition 2 ){
        throw;
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "something is wrong";
}
```

As you see, my `catch` block has its own error message, And that message is a constant. So really I don't need to pass a message when I use `throw` like this:

```
throw new Exception('error message');
```

Well can I use `throw` without anything? I just need to jump into `catch` block.

Honestly writing an **useless** error message is annoying for me.

---

As you know my current code has a syntax error: *(it referring to `throw;`)*

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected ';' in {path}

Comment: You need to throw an instance of the `Exception` class. If you don't have a message - don't write it: `throw new Exception();`

Comment: @Marty As I said, this error `something is wrong` is always fixed for all `throw`s .. So why should I write it several times?!!

Comment: Exceptions are supposed to provide *useful* information. You're going to want to punch past you in the face when you come back to work on the app and constantly see the extremely ambiguous "something is wrong".

Comment: @zerkms Emm no sure what you mean .. Can you please write an answer?

Comment: I mean: if you don't put a message into the exception constructor - just don't: `throw new Exception();`

Comment: Exception handling is not a method of control flow

Comment: Exceptions are supposed to inform other developer what went wrong? Why wouldn't you? @Marty is right, if someone depends on your code they are gonna curse you at some point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`message` parameter is optional in the `Exception` constructor. So if you don't have/want to put - just don't:

```
throw new Exception;
```

But you still must throw an instance of the `Exception` class (or a class that extends it), since it is a part of the php language syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all your exceptions to have the same message, you can extend it and define the message in your class:

```
class AmbiguousException extends Exception {
    public function __construct($message = 'Something is wrong.', $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
       parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    } 
}
```

Then:

```
throw new AmbiguousException();
```

Comment: Hah .. writing a class just for one-error-message .. funny. Thx +1

Comment: @Shafizadeh I think you're undervaluing exceptions. They provide things like a complete strack track so you can actually see the chain of method calls that provided the error. They're not simple messages.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> The thrown object must be an instance of the Exception class or a subclass of Exception. Trying to throw an object that is not will result in a PHP Fatal Error.

You can throw an exception without any message:

```
throw new Exception();
```

Perhaps something to help you from duplicating the same exception is as follows:

```
$e = new Exception('something is wrong');

try {
    throw $e;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below throw everytime you need.

```
throw new Exception();
```

and catch will remain same as your code.

Comment: As @zerkms mentioned in his answer, you also can omit `()`. thx anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance with default message and then throw that instance.

```
$Exception = new Exception("some error message!");
try {
    throw $Exception;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `throw` keyword on its own. However, you can use `throw new Exception();` without specify the `$message` parameter, because it'll just fallback to the default message. Check out the Exceptions section in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: Yeah trust me I've checked the manual out before asking my question `;-)`..! thx anyway for your answer.